# Weird symbol has replaced the letter "h"

Tags: 14.04, installed-programs

I just recently installed pipelight and netflix desktop and now it looks like a weird symbol has replaced the letter "h".

Screenshoot:

[image: 0]

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04